# Override HTML element visibility controlled by a <details> tag

Tags: html, css, visibility

I wanted to make an element inside a `<details>` tag be visible even if the `<details>` tag is not open using CSS styles. I tried using `visibility`, `display`, `position`, modifying the `<details>` tag height, etc. but nothing worked.

In this example I want the second paragraph to be visible even after closing the `<details>` tag:

```html
<details>
  <summary>Category</summary>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p> An another paragraph</p>
</details>
```

How could I achieve this? Is this possible to do without manipulating the DOM structure?

Comment: Basically, no!!

Comment: You could do it with JavaScript by looping the details elements and creating an html element with the contents of the last paragraph of the details elements on load and destroying/re-creating when the details element changes state. I don't see any css/html option available to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: this DOES manipulate the DOM structure.

You cannot do this strictly with CSS that I know of however you can clone the paragraph and append it after the `<details>` element - might effect you style and you may need to account for that somehow.

Here is a verbose version of the script to show what it is doing.
Note I added a class to the paragraph in the details to hide it always...

If this does not provide enough you might need to update something during the toggle event ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#events

```js
let details = document.querySelector('details');
let secondP = details.querySelector('p:last-of-type');
let clonedSecond = secondP.cloneNode(true);
secondP.classList.add('hide-me');
details.after(clonedSecond);
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Category</summary>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p> An another paragraph</p>
</details>
```